# Choosing where newlines are in a multi-line string literal

Tags: rust

If I create the following multi-line string literal:

```
let lit = "A -> B
           C -> D
           E -> F";
```

It prints out like this:

```
A -> B
          C -> D
          E -> F
```

No surprise. However, if I try this:

```
let lit = "A -> B\
           C -> D\
           E -> F";
```

I get:

```
A -> BC -> DE -> F
```

What I'm trying to get is this:

```
A -> B
C -> D
E -> F
```

But this is the best thing I've come up with:

```
let lit = "A -> B\n\
           C -> D\n\
           E -> F";
```

Or maybe this:

```
let lit = vec!["A -> B", "C -> D", "E -> F"].connect("\n");
```

Both of those feel a little clunky, though not terrible. Just wondering if there's any cleaner way?

Comment: Code review would be better suited for this.

Comment: @EvanCarslake this is totally hypothetical code, which is outside the scope of Code Review. Please see [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778/23788).

Comment: @Mat'sMug my mistake. I can't help you though.

Answer (score 3):

[Indoc](https://github.com/dtolnay/indoc) is a procedural macro that does what you want. It stands for "indented document." It provides a macro called `indoc!()` that takes a multiline string literal and un-indents it so the leftmost non-space character is in the first column.

```
let lit = indoc! {"
    A -> B
    C -> D
    E -> F"
};
```

The result is `"A -> B\nC -> D\nE -> F"` as you asked for.

Whitespace is preserved relative to the leftmost non-space character in the document, so the following preserves 2 spaces before "C":

```
let lit = indoc! {"
    A -> B
      C -> D
    E -> F"
};
```

The result is `"A -> B\n  C -> D\nE -> F"`.

Answer (score 0):

I see three other possible solutions:

1) Get rid of the spaces:

```
let lit = "A -> B
C -> D
E -> F";
```

This way, you lose the neat display in your code.  You could get that back like this:

2) Get rid of the spaces, shift everything down a line, and escape the return.

```
let lit = "\
A -> B
C -> D
E -> F";
```

I would explain what that "\" is doing in a comment, though, because it isn't obvious otherwise.

3) Combine these two solutions:

```
let lit = 
"A -> B
C -> D
E -> F";
```

You can test this at [Ideone](http://ideone.com/TMbkQQ).

Comment: I was using 1) initially. The problem is it looks pretty bad with indented code.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Thank you.

Comment: @anderspitman: Isn't it a generic issue with indented code and multi-line? I seem to remember similar issues with Python...

Comment: You could use spaces in the assignment, then substitute away any line-initial spaces. This is mildly inefficient, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly as an exercise, I mimicked Python's `join` syntax with the following:

```
trait CanJoin {
    fn join(&self, in_strings: Vec<&str>) -> String;
}

impl CanJoin for str {
    fn join(&self, in_strings: Vec<&str>) -> String {
        in_strings.connect(self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vector = vec!["A -> B", "B -> C", "C -> D"];
    let joined = "\n".join(vector);
}
```

Or as a macro:

```
macro_rules! join_lines {
    ($($x:tt)*) => {
        {
            vec![$($x)*].connect("\n")
        }
    }
}

let joined = join_lines!("A -> B", "B -> C", "C -> D");
```

Comment: Using a vector here is overkill. `["a", "b"].connect("-")` is sufficient.

Comment: Also note that `connect` is [being renamed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1102-rename-connect-to-join.md) to `join`.